# add a child class from an outside parent via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I add a child class from an outside parent using JavaScript?

For example, in CSS it would look like this for the class:

```css
.custominput2> tdbody> tr> td> input
```

If the field is not empty, then add the class "line2" where you have the closest "line" class.

Staying as follows:

```html
<div class = "line line2"> </div>
```

Example of how I was trying:

```
$('.custominput2 > tbody > tr > td > input[type=text][value]:not([value=""])').each(function () {
    $(this).closest('div.line').addClass('line2');
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group form-groupmargin col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 order-md-0 col-sm-6 order-sm-0 col-6 order-0 px-2">
   <table id="Nome_ET" class="dxeValidDynEditorTable dxeRoot_MaterialCompact" style="width:100%;" errorframe="errorFrame">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td id="Nome_CapC" class="dxeCaptionHALSys dxeCaptionVATSys dxeTextEditCTypeSys dxeCLTSys dxeCaptionCell_MaterialCompact"><label class="dxeCaption_MaterialCompact Lato-Bold filtersubtitle" for="Nome_I">Nome Edital:</label><em class="dxeRequiredMark_MaterialCompact">*</em></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id="Nome_CC" style="width:100%;">
               <table class="dxeTextBoxSys dxeTextBox_MaterialCompact form-control Lato-Regular custominput custominput2 p-0 px-2 pallete1-devexpressinput dxeTextBoxDefaultWidthSys" id="Nome" style="width:100%;"> /* FIND THE INPUT FROM HERE */
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="dxic" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_MaterialCompact dxeEditAreaSys" id="Nome_I" name="Nome" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('Nome')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('Nome')" onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged('Nome')" value="____/____" type="text"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="display: none;">
            <td id="Nome_EC" class="dxeErrorCell_MaterialCompact dxeErrorFrame_MaterialCompact dxeErrorFrameSys dxeErrorCellSys dxeNoBorderTop" style="display:none;">
               <table style="width:100%;">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td><img id="Nome_EI" class="dxEditors_edtError_MaterialCompact" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_88-h__yk" alt=""></td>
                        <td id="Nome_ETC" style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;">Valor inválido</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <script id="dxss_518598026" data-executed="true">
      <!--
      ASPx.createControl(ASPxClientTextBox,'Nome','',{'stateObject':{'rawValue':''},'captionPosition':'Top','customValidationEnabled':true,'isValid':true,'errorText':'Valor inválido','validationPatterns':[new ASPx.RequiredFieldValidationPattern('Edital obrigatório'),new ASPx.RegularExpressionValidationPattern('Edital incorreto', '[0-9]{4}\\/?(19\\d\\d|20[0-2]\\d|2030)')],'setFocusOnError':true,'isErrorFrameRequired':true,'display':'Dynamic','errorImageIsAssigned':true,'controlCellStyles':{'cssClass':'dxeErrorFrame_MaterialCompact dxeErrorFrameSys dxeNoBorderBottom dxeControlsCell_MaterialCompact','style':'width:100%;'},'nullText':'____/____','errorCellPosition':'Bottom'},null,null,{'decorationStyles':[{'key':'I','className':'dxeInvalid_MaterialCompact','cssText':''},{'key':'F','className':'dxeFocused_MaterialCompact','cssText':''},{'key':'N','className':'dxeNullText_MaterialCompact','cssText':''}],'maskInfo':{'maskText':'0000/0000','dateTimeOnly':false,'properties':{'errorText':'Edital inválido'}}});

      //-->
   </script>
   <div class="line"></div> /* ADD CLASS LINE2 HERE */
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just target the element in css `.custominput2 > tbody > tr > td > input[type=text][value]:not([value=""]){}`?

Comment: Hello, because I need to add a style to <div class = "line">, not the input. But to add the style to the div, I need to validate the input first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you caramba! for the tip!

I made it work, I had to make some changes to my input. my input has a defined value which is the mask configured by the devexpress component.

For example, my input is already filled with the value **_ /**  or ---.---- or **._** and etc.

I had to remove all special characters from the value, and define it in another attribute called customvalue.

Now I validate whether the customvalue is empty or not, so I can add the class to the div

it was like this:

i have to create 2 class below:

```
                        .line2 {
                            width: 100% !important;
                            background-color: red !important;
                        }

                        .line3{
                            width: 100% !important;
                            background-color: blue ;
                        }
```

in the javascript i do:

```
$.fn.materializeInputs = function (selectors) {

    // default param with backwards compatibility
    if (typeof (selectors) === 'undefined') selectors = "input, textarea";

    // attribute function
    function setInputValueAttr(element) {
        element.setAttribute('customvalue', element.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ""));
        element.setAttribute('value', element.value);


        if (element.getAttribute("customvalue") !== '') {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').children('div.line').addClass('line3');

        }
        else {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').children('div.line').removeClass('line3');

        }

    }

    // set value attribute at load
    this.find(selectors).each(function () {
        setInputValueAttr(this);
    });

    // on keyup
    this.on("keyup", selectors, function () {
        setInputValueAttr(this);
    });


    this.find(selectors).focusin(function () {
        $(this).closest('div.form-group').children('div.line').addClass('line2');

    });

    this.find(selectors).focusout(function () {
        $(this).closest('div.form-group').children('div.line').removeClass('line2');
    });



$('document').ready(function () {
    // enable material-style inputs in entire body
    $('body').materializeInputs();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. The minimal change is change
from:

```
 $(this).closest('div.line').addClass('line2');
```

to:

```
$(this).closest('div').children('.line').addClass('line2');
```

or: (just to make it more clear)

```
$(this).closest('div.form-group').children('div.line').addClass('line2');
```

because the [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will match the closest element and from that one you will need to find the child element `.line` or `div.line`

```js
$('.custominput2 > tbody > tr > td > input[type=text][value]:not([value=""])').each(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').children('.line').addClass('line2');
});
```

```css
.line2 {
  border: solid 5px fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-groupmargin col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 order-md-0 col-sm-6 order-sm-0 col-6 order-0 px-2">
   <table id="Nome_ET" class="dxeValidDynEditorTable dxeRoot_MaterialCompact" style="width:100%;" errorframe="errorFrame">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td id="Nome_CapC" class="dxeCaptionHALSys dxeCaptionVATSys dxeTextEditCTypeSys dxeCLTSys dxeCaptionCell_MaterialCompact"><label class="dxeCaption_MaterialCompact Lato-Bold filtersubtitle" for="Nome_I">Nome Edital:</label><em class="dxeRequiredMark_MaterialCompact">*</em></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id="Nome_CC" style="width:100%;">
               <table class="dxeTextBoxSys dxeTextBox_MaterialCompact form-control Lato-Regular custominput custominput2 p-0 px-2 pallete1-devexpressinput dxeTextBoxDefaultWidthSys" id="Nome" style="width:100%;"> /* FIND THE INPUT FROM HERE */
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="dxic" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_MaterialCompact dxeEditAreaSys" id="Nome_I" name="Nome" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('Nome')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('Nome')" onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged('Nome')" value="____/____" type="text"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="display: none;">
            <td id="Nome_EC" class="dxeErrorCell_MaterialCompact dxeErrorFrame_MaterialCompact dxeErrorFrameSys dxeErrorCellSys dxeNoBorderTop" style="display:none;">
               <table style="width:100%;">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td><img id="Nome_EI" class="dxEditors_edtError_MaterialCompact" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_88-h__yk" alt=""></td>
                        <td id="Nome_ETC" style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;">Valor inválido</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <script id="dxss_518598026" data-executed="true">
// what ever code is here, inside the script tag you can use javascripts "//" comment notation
</script>
   <div class="line"></div> /* ADD CLASS LINE2 HERE */
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example as an if statement. Notice the specificity and use of trim to make sure there's no white space. That way if the input is blank the class will be added.

```js
if ($.trim($('.custominput2 input[type=text]').val()) == '') {
  $('.line').addClass('line2');
}
```

```css
.line2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-groupmargin col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 order-md-0 col-sm-6 order-sm-0 col-6 order-0 px-2">
  <table id="Nome_ET" class="dxeValidDynEditorTable dxeRoot_MaterialCompact" style="width:100%;" errorframe="errorFrame">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="Nome_CapC" class="dxeCaptionHALSys dxeCaptionVATSys dxeTextEditCTypeSys dxeCLTSys dxeCaptionCell_MaterialCompact"><label class="dxeCaption_MaterialCompact Lato-Bold filtersubtitle" for="Nome_I">Nome Edital:</label><em class="dxeRequiredMark_MaterialCompact">*</em></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="Nome_CC" style="width:100%;">
          <table class="dxeTextBoxSys dxeTextBox_MaterialCompact form-control Lato-Regular custominput custominput2 p-0 px-2 pallete1-devexpressinput dxeTextBoxDefaultWidthSys" id="Nome" style="width:100%;"> /* FIND THE INPUT FROM HERE */
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="dxic" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_MaterialCompact dxeEditAreaSys" id="Nome_I" name="Nome" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('Nome')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('Nome')" onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged('Nome')" value="" type="text"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="display: none;">
        <td id="Nome_EC" class="dxeErrorCell_MaterialCompact dxeErrorFrame_MaterialCompact dxeErrorFrameSys dxeErrorCellSys dxeNoBorderTop" style="display:none;">
          <table style="width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><img id="Nome_EI" class="dxEditors_edtError_MaterialCompact" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_88-h__yk" alt=""></td>
                <td id="Nome_ETC" style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;">Valor inválido</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="line">ADD CLASS LINE2 HERE</div> 
</div>
```